# Filter DataTable to Include Only items in a column that matches a String

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, epplus

I have ***DataTable*** that is bound to a ***Binding Source*** which forms the **DataSource** of **DataGridView**

In order to filter the contents of the DataGridView i set the following filter

```
bs.Filter = string.Format("Result LIKE '%{0}%'", "Match");
```

This works fine.But now i need to export the Matched items in the DataTable to an Excel file. I'm using ***EPPlus*** Library and I'm saving the file using the following code

```
var excel = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet-name");
// you can also use LoadFromCollection with an `IEnumerable<SomeType>`
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(mydatatable, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light1);
ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address.ToString()].AutoFitColumns();    
using (var file = File.Create(dia.FileName))
    excel.SaveAs(file);
```

How can i filter the items in DataTable in a similar manner as i do with the DataGridView ?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the datatable using the Select() method, copy the results into a new datatable and use that to load your worksheet. Try this:

```
var expression = string.Format("Result LIKE '%{0}%'", "Match");
var filteredResults = sourceTable.Select(expression).CopyToDataTable();
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(filteredResults, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light1);
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please don't forget to mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cast datasource  to DataTable and use `DataTable.DefaultView` property which will contains filtered data.

```
var source = (BindingSource)datagridView.DataSource;
var data = (DataTable)source.DataSource;
var filteredData = data.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

For filtering DataTable use `Select` method and pass there same expression

```
var filterBy = "Match";
var filter = $"Result LIKE '%{filterBy}%'"
var fileteredRows = originalDataTable.Select(filter).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I cannot use this method as i don't want to show the user the filtered data in the the datatable .I want to do the filtering internally.

Comment: @jim, even if you do not want to present the filtered data to the user, you can still use the `DefaultView` technique presented in the answer.  `DefaultView` is a instance of [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can create a `DataView` of the `DataTable` with the required filter and call the `ToTable` method on that view.